# How to find conflict between my CSS and JQuery UI CSS?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, firebug, conflict

im using JQuery UI on my website to make for example buttons. It seems like my stylesheets are interefereing with the JQuery UI CSS because the button font-size is too big. How can i find out what's causing the problem? I installed Firebug 1.7 on FF 4.0 but i see it's mostly using JUI CSS from and from  my stylesheet just some derived styles which should not affect the font-size of the button. Can someone help how to make the buttons look like they should?

Test page: http://kangurek24.pl/test/loginform.jsp.htm

Comment: firebug should be showing where the styles are coming from. what does it say? screenshot?

Comment: jQuery UI.css line 59. .ui-widget has em font sizes set

Comment: I think it's because UI is using EM. I'm not well versed in CSS but if I understand correctly, EM values tend to depend what the current normal font size is.

Answer (score 3):

The `font-size: 18px;` comes from the jQuery UI CSS rule on line 59 of [`jquery-ui.css`](http://kangurek24.pl/test/loginform.jsp_pliki/jquery-ui.css).

```
.ui-widget {
    /* snip */
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

The default font size is 16px, and `1.1 * 16 = 17.6 ≅ 18`.

To give the buttons the same font size as the rest of the text, add this rule to your custom CSS:

```
.ui-button {
    font-size: .91em; /* ≅ 1/1.1 */ 
}
```

Make sure that your custom CSS comes after the jQuery UI CSS.